# What are these <references> PHPStorm expected

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following Codesnippet

```
pg_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN 'machine';");
pg_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE license DROP COLUMN 'machine';");
```

I use PHP-Storm and it throws this error after editing another Line:

```
<reference> or IF exepected, got 'machine'
<reference> or IF exepected, got 'machine'
```

The error is Marked on those two Lines above. What does PHP-Storm wanted to tell me. I neither need an IF

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove single quotes from column name since those will be treated as strings instead of object identifier. If you really need to quote object identifier, then you need to use double quotes.

So this should work:

```
pg_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN machine;");
pg_query($conn, "ALTER TABLE license DROP COLUMN machine;");
```